# Replace multiple strings in multiple files with R

Tags: r, gsub, file-management

I have something like 700,000 files in a folder where I need to find and replace multiple strings with different other strings (all 4 caracters codes). It is unsure if a string is present or not in a file. I'm trying to use gsub but I can't find how to do it with regular expressions. Can someone tell me a good and efficient way to handle this task?

This is the code I've used so far. It worked well with only one `y <- gsub(...)` instruction but doesn't work for my purpose, obviously because only the last gsub instruction is taken into account for defining the y variable...

```
chm_files <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=("^[[:digit:]]*.chm$"), full.names=F)

for(chm_file in chm_files) {
  x <- readLines(chm_file)
  y <- gsub("AG02|AG07|AG05|AG18|AG19|AG08|AG09|AG17", "AGRL", x)
  y <- gsub("SB28|SB42|SB43|SB33|SB41|SB34|SB39|SB35", "SWHT", x)
  y <- gsub("WB28|WB42|WB43|WB32|WB09|WB33|WB41|WB26", "BARL", x)
  y <- gsub("WW02|WW25|WW08|WW31|WW05|WW28|WW19|WW42", "WWHT", x)
  cat(y, file=chm_file, sep="\n")
}
```

Comment: what platform are you on? why not use a [shell script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/)? you dont have to use r for everything

Comment: I use win 8.1...  I know nearly nothing about shell script. This task is only a tiny part of the code I have to use to analysis my data and I do everthing with R. Maybe shell script can be integrated in my code, I don't know.. will check, thanks for the idea..

Comment: If you always assigned back to `x` rather than `y` you would not loose the earlier corrections.

Comment: There are several free text editors with the ability to do "batch" editing of files (under windows).  That's probably cleaner, faster, and easier than coding up `R`

Comment: actually I will do it many times and it's part of other tasks in R so I prefer to code it once for all and let it run to get the results without any intervention..

Comment: I found a *.CHM file extension in your R Code sample. CHM are compiled and binary. Are these files really Compiler Help Modules (CHM)?

Comment: No, they are ASCII files containing parameters for a model.

Comment: If you ever have to look at it again, I would also make it easier to work with gsub("AG(02|05|07|08|09|17|18|19)", "AGRL", x)
or gsub("AG(0[257-9]|1[7-9])", "AGRL", x)
or gsub("AG(0[25]|[0-1][7-9])", "AGRL", x) whatever structure makes sense for the context.

Comment: Good point, thank you! it will simplify a bit my code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure there are already numerous pre-built functions for this task in various R-packages, but anyhow I just cooked this one up for myself and others to use/modify. Apart from the tasks request above it also prints out a tracking log of the count of all changes made across files function: [multi_replace](https://gist.github.com/mattjbayly/9c56ec80ae291ff00589ffa3440806a1).

Here is some example code of how it should be run

```
# local directory with files you want to work with
setwd("C:/Users/DW/Desktop/New folder")
# get a list of files based on a pattern of interest e.g. .html, .txt, .php 
filer = list.files(pattern=".php")
# f - list of original string values you want to change
f <- c("localhost","dbtest","root","oldpassword")
# r - list of values to replace the above values with
# make sure the indexing of f & r
r <- c("newhost", "newdb", "newroot", "newpassword")

# Run the function and watch all your changes take place ;)
tracking_sheet <- multi_replace(filer, f, r)
tracking_sheet
```

Answer (score -2):

```
setwd("D:/R Training Material Kathmandu/File renaming procedures")
filer = list.files(pattern="2016")
f <- c("DATA,","$")
r <- c("","")
tracking_sheet <- multi_replace(filer, f, r)
tracking_sheet
```

I used the above script but the code failed to replace the $ sign among all files